# Azure DevOps role for inviting AAD users and groups

Tags: azure-devops

I am currently exploring the various roles and permissions within Azure DevOps, specifically in relation to Azure Active Directory (AAD) users and groups. I am interested in understanding if there exists a role, other than the Project Collection Administrator role, that has the capability to invite AAD users and AAD groups into Azure DevOps.

Thank you very much for every hint.

[DevOps screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIycs.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can allow team and project administrators to invite new users. By default (I think) this should be enabled. You can review the settings by completing the following steps:

1. Go to "Organization Settins"
2. Go to "Security" > "Policies"
3. Enable "Allow team and project administrators to invite new users"

[image: Azure DevOps: organization settins > security > policies]

More information can be found on the Microsoft documentation pages: [Restrict new user invitations from Project and Team Administrators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/restrict-invitations?view=azure-devops).

> By default, all administrators can invite new users to their Azure DevOps organization. Disabling this policy blocks Team and Project Administrators from inviting new users. Project Collection Administrators (PCAs) can add new users to the organization, regardless of the policy status. If a user is already a member of the organization, Project and Team Administrators can add that user to a project.